# EFCore/ASP.NET Core Many-to-many relation: JsonSerializer ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore not working as expected

Tags: asp.net-core, json.net, ef-core-2.2

I have an issue with the ASP.NET Core JsonSerializer. It keeps running into an infinite reference loop even though I explicitly set the ReferenceLoopHandling property to ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore.

I have the details in this github issue: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/14997

EDIT:

The whole Startup configuration code:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  // Deserialize specific settings into living objects
  services.Configure<JwtSettings>(this.Configuration.GetSection("Jwt"));
  services.Configure<CookieSettings>(this.Configuration.GetSection("Cookies"));

  // Read settings to apply locally
  DatabasesSettings dbSettings = DatabasesSettings.GetDatabasesSettings(this.Configuration);
  JwtSettings jwtSettings = this.Configuration.GetSection("Jwt").Get<JwtSettings>();
  CookieSettings cookieSettings = this.Configuration.GetSection("Cookies").Get<CookieSettings>();

  switch (dbSettings[DatabaseConstants.DatabaseSettingsData].Provider)
  {
    case "mysql":
      services.AddEntityFrameworkMySql()
              .AddDbContext<DataContext>(options => options.UseMySql(ConnectionStringBuilder.BuildConnectionString(dbSettings[DatabaseConstants.DatabaseSettingsData])));
      break;
    case "mssql":
      services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer()
              .AddDbContext<DataContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(ConnectionStringBuilder.BuildConnectionString(dbSettings[DatabaseConstants.DatabaseSettingsData])));
      break;
  }

  // Identity MUST precede AUTHENTICATION in order to produce correct 401 Unauthorized instead of 404 Not found
  services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>(options =>
  {
    options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
    options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
    options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
    options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
    options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
    options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
  }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<DataContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();

  // JWT Bearer Token Authentication configuration secretKey contains a secret passphrase only your server knows
  Action<JwtBearerOptions> jwtOptions = options =>
  {
    options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
    {
      OnTokenValidated = context =>
      {
        // Get the EF Context responsbile for authentication
        DataContext dbContext = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<DataContext>();

        List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>
        {
          new Claim("AuthorizedAccess", "true"),
        };

        // Add claim(s) based on user -- todo
        ClaimsIdentity appIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims);
        context.Principal.AddIdentity(appIdentity);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
      }
    };
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
      // Do not validate lifetime. Need logout to invalidate. todo: verify if we can leave it this way
      ValidateLifetime = jwtSettings.Expiration.Enabled,

      // If you want to allow a certain amount of clock drift, set that here:
      ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(jwtSettings.Expiration.ClockDrift),

      // Validate the JWT Issuer (iss) claim
      ValidateIssuer = true,
      ValidIssuer = jwtSettings.Issuer,

      // Validate the JWT Audience (aud) claim
      ValidateAudience = true,
      ValidAudience = jwtSettings.Audience,

      // The signing key must match!
      ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
      IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jwtSettings.Key)),

      SaveSigninToken = true
    };
  };
  // Authentication Service
  services.AddAuthentication(
    options =>
    {
      options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
      options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    }).AddJwtBearer(jwtOptions).AddCookie();

  // Authorization Service
  services.AddAuthorization(
    options =>
    {
      options.AddPolicy(PolicyNames.AdministrationPolicy, policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new AuthorizationNameRequirement(PolicyNames.AdministrationPolicy)));
      options.AddPolicy(PolicyNames.PurchasePolicy, policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new AuthorizationNameRequirement(PolicyNames.PurchasePolicy)));
      options.AddPolicy(PolicyNames.TradePolicy, policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new AuthorizationNameRequirement(PolicyNames.TradePolicy)));
      options.AddPolicy(PolicyNames.ExchangePolicy, policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new AuthorizationNameRequirement(PolicyNames.ExchangePolicy)));
    });

  // Application Cookie
  services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(
    options =>
    {
      // Avoid redirecting REST clients on 401
      options.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
      {
        OnRedirectToLogin = ctx =>
        {
          ctx.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
          return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
      };

      options.Cookie.Name = cookieSettings.ApplicationCookieName;
    });

  // Antiforgery
  services.AddAntiforgery(
    options =>
    {
      options.Cookie.Name = cookieSettings.AntiforgeryCookieName;
      options.Cookie.Domain = cookieSettings.AntiforgeryCookieDomain;
      options.Cookie.Path = "/";
      options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
    });

  // Additional Services
  services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, AuthorizationNameHandler>();

  // Cross Origin Policies
  services.AddCors(
    options =>
    {
      options.AddPolicy("AllowAnyOrigin", builder => { builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowCredentials().Build(); });
    });

  // Enable Response Compression
  services.AddResponseCompression();

  // MVC
  services.AddMvc(
    options =>
    {
      options.Filters.Add(new CorsAuthorizationFilterFactory("AllowAnyOrigin"));
      options.CacheProfiles.Add(
        "Default",
        new CacheProfile()
        {
          Duration = 60
        });
      options.CacheProfiles.Add(
        "Never",
        new CacheProfile()
        {
          Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None,
          NoStore = true
        });
    }).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2).AddJsonOptions(
    options =>
    {
      options.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
      options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
      options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
    });

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
  if (Program.IsDebug)
  {
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
  }
  else
  {
    app.UseHsts();
  }

  app.UseCors("AllowAnyOrigin");

  // app.UseCorsMiddleware(); // Custom middleware
  app.UseHttpsRedirection();

  app.UseDefaultFiles();
  app.UseStaticFiles();
  app.UseAuthentication();
  app.UseResponseCompression();

  app.UseMvc();
}
```

Comment: Show your startup configuration code that you have tried.

Comment: @TanvirArjel here you go

Answer (score 0):

You can configure `Json.NET` to ignore cycles that it finds in the object graph. This is done in the `ConfigureServices(...`) method in `Startup.cs` as follows:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...

    services.AddMvc()
        .AddJsonOptions(
            options => options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
        );

    ...
}
```

In your code replace `options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Error;` with the following:

```
options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
```

Comment: Well I am sorry. I put code there that I have tested once and forgot to change it back. I actually had it on Ignore. It still does not work.

Comment: In the github issue you can see, that I use Ignore as the JSON setting. I just took the wrong code for this question. Changed it now.

Comment: Have to tried again with `ignore` again? Is not working? If not then what is the error message is it showing?

Comment: Yes I've tried it with Ignore. No it is not working and there is no specific error message. The serializer just keeps resolving the self references in an infinite loop. When I set the setting to Error, the Serializer even warns me about the self references, which is perfectly correct. But why doesnt it ignore them if I tell it to??